# encapsulating class calls/modifies things in the dir of original class

Tags: python, oop, encapsulation

I have a class A encapsulating a class B instance and additional stuff. The following is a toy example.

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 2
    def square(self):
        return self.b * self.b

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.b = B()

a = A(1)
print(a.b.square())
```

Any time an A instance wants to call a  method in B, I always need to do things like 'a.b'. My hope is to get rid of '.b' for user convenience. The following codes do the job.

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 2
    def square(self):
        return self.b * self.b

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.b = B()
    def square(self):
        return self.b.square()

a = A(1)
print(a.square())
```

The problem is that class B is from outside library and there are lots of and different types of things in the **dir**. I couldn't do it one by one manually like above. Any magical ways to handle that?

Comment: It looks like you should have A inherit from B.

Comment: I did use inheritance at first, but due to some restriction of the parent class, some functionality cannot be inherited properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any magical ways to handle that?

It's python, of course there are! You can use `__getattr__` function to proxy unknown calls to `b`:

```
class B(object):
    def shadowed(self):
        print('B.shadowed')

    def unshadowed(self):
        print('B.unshadowed')


class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._b = B()

    def shadowed(self):
        print('A.shadowed')

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._b, name)


test = A()
test.shadowed()
test.unshadowed()
test.unknown()
```

Result:

```
A.shadowed
B.unshadowed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Andrew/Desktop/test.py", line 23, in <module>
    test.unknown()
  File "/Users/Andrew/Desktop/test.py", line 17, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._b, name)
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'unknown'
```

`__getattr__` is called when the object doesn't have attribute that's being asked for.

Comment: Thanks a lot! A further question. You essentially overwrite the shadowed function in class A FROM SCRATCH. What if only making some small modification to the shadowed function in class B? One can certainly do the following: def shadowed(self): self._b.shadowed() print('addtional stuff'). Any ways to get rid of ._b in this setting?

Comment: @J.Lin unfortunately I can't think of any non-hacky way to do so. You could get this via inheritance and calling `super().shadowed()`, but unfortunately you can't use inheritance... You can do something horrifically awesome via [framehacking](http://farmdev.com/src/secrets/framehack/), but this is just too crazy for not typing _b.

Comment: I c. Anyways, it's already good enough for my purpose. Thank you!